# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in line 5

Tags: php, массивы

```
$mod_settings = array();

$create_settings_array = explode(";", trim($all_modules[5][$i]));

foreach ($create_settings_array as $value) {

    $set_one_sets = explode("=", trim($value));

    $mod_settings[trim($set_one_sets[0])] = trim($set_one_sets[1]); // нету этого элемента почему-то

    if($mod_settings[trim($set_one_sets[0])] == NULL)
        unset($mod_settings[trim($set_one_sets[0])]);
}
```

Подскажите, почему выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: а в `$create_settings_array ` что-то есть? вы уверены?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский точно, почему-то передаётся три массива, а не два как должно быть. Интересно откуда он берётся лишний?

Comment: Прошу прощения, я догнал. Ведь explode делит `;` на две части, значит третий у нас пустой)

Comment: explode делит не на две части, а по делимитерам ..их может быть и 1000...... а вот что вы там со всем вытворяете - эт надо смотреть. там похоже это всё у вас в цикле, до цикла еще что-то. а по отдельному куску кода только вот ответ - что c `$create_settings_array ` не все в порядке

Comment: Заработало, я извлёк последний элемент массива `array_pop($create_settings_array);`